# npm build throws error TS2305: Module '"bson"' has no exported member 'Map'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, express-session

Code (ts node) was building fine until I started trying to add mongo support for express sessions.  Out of nowhere, I start getting this error:

```
> server@1.0.0 build
> tsc

node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts:20:10 - error TS2305: Module '"bson"' has no exported member 'Map'.

20 import { Map as Map_2 } from 'bson';
            ~~~


Found 1 error in node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts:20
```

Here's what I assume is a relevant subsection of my package.json:

```
        "connect-mongodb-session": "^3.1.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "express-session": "^1.17.3",
        "express-static": "^1.2.6",
        "googleapis": "^128.0.0",
        "mongodb": "^6.3.0",
        "mongoose": "^8.0.2",
```

I can't find anyone else who's had this problem, so I assume I have something configured incorrectly, maybe it's a versioning issue.

I tried building the code as usual, but I have this error now.